# Is it possible to convert an ASCII integer to a character without access to builtins?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.7, assuming we have no access to functions such as `str()` and must rely entirely on `int.__str__()` etc., is it possible to get the character represented by an ASCII integer? E.G

```py
>>> a = 97
>>> b = a.__magicfunction__()
>>> b
'a'
```

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or is there a real background?

Comment: @KlausD. No real use case, but I've always found working out solutions to restricted Python problems fun

Comment: I don't think so no

Comment: Can we use any class methods, or only dunder methods?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi All class methods

Comment: `"%c" % a` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def magicfunction(i):
    ascii=[None] * 32
    ascii+=[' ', '!', "'", '#', '$', '%', '&', '"', '(', ')', '*', '+', '`', '-', '+', '/']
    ascii+=list('0123456789:;<=>?@')
    ascii+=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    ascii+=list('[\]^_`')
    ascii+=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

    return ascii[i]

print(magicfunction(97))
```

produces:

```
a
```

Answer (score 0):

You never said we should not use `bytes`:

```
bytes([97]).decode()
```